# How can I change Bitnami Sonarqube VM to Enterprise Edition

Tags: azure, sonarqube, bitnami

Bitnami offers a SonarQube preconfigured VM, complete with database and all configured to work out of the box.

The SonarQube that comes in this VM is the community edition. Is there a way I can install the Enterprise Edition instead of community edition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The different SonarQube editions have different components bundled in them, so there isn't a way of just 'updating' between editions: you'd have to use a completely different distribution.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. I have EE downloaded on the machine, but I don't know how to get it working properly with the bitnami launcher and configuration

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here, you will need to follow its official documentation https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE67/Enterprise+Edition or just replace the files under the `/opt/bitnami/apps/sonarqube/sonarqube/` folder with the files of the edition you want to use. Remember to create a backup first. More information [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/sonarqube/administration/upgrade/#upgrade-only-sonarqube-in-the-bitnami-sonarqube-stack)